# How can I procedurally modify the hair portion of this texture to better match the intended color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I have this texture for the head and hair of a humanoid 3D model:

[image]

That is the version of the texture re-saved as a .JPG.  For reference's sake, here is the original in .PNG format:

[image]

This character should have dark brown or black hair, as shown at location #1 in the pic.  The actual hair portions of the model are textured by what appears in locations #2 and #3.  There is some kind of a translation happening in the model's source application which converts the hair from the multicolored blob in the lower right corner into its correct, darker appearance.  I haven't been successful in reversing that effect.  What I would like to do is to take this image file into Photoshop and edit it so that the colors of the multicolored blob (#2) align with the intended color of the hair (#1), while still keeping the details shown at #2.  How can I do this?

Comment: You might get more responses on a Stack exchange site dedicated to 3D technology

Comment: I've tried that.  It looks like there's no known way to fix this from the source, so I'm trying  to do this in Photoshop.

Comment: I don't work with 3d models, but I suspect that "some kind of a translation happening in the model's source application" is super important information for anyone to help. Perhaps edit your question to mention the application. In addition, your "original PNG format image" is a jpg. If the PNG does not look "normal" when opened then the channels are probably RGB (or RGBA) but repurposed for use by the source application and are meant to be edited per-channel. Again, knowing the source application might lead to documentation etc that may be of use.